# Relative path & http vs https

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a site where all http requests are redirected to https. So a certain page is served via https. I'm using jQuery's `.load()` function to retrieve a url. I'm using a relative path ('/pagename/'). For some reason it is trying to retrieve that relative path via http instead of https. So I'm getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://example.com/pagename/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Anyone know why is not trying to retrieve this page from https on a relative path?

Sample code:

```
$('.edit-icon').click(function(e) {
    var id = this.id.split('-')[1];
    $('#my-modal-icon').load("/envelopes/edit-icon/0/" + id).modal('open');
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code, not just a description

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The real URL ended in a backslash. So the browser was attempting to redirect to the same URL with a backslash at the end, but http instead of https. The fix was as simple as `.load("/envelopes/edit-icon/0/" + id + "/")`